# Full width <div> with margin-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I am building a website with Wordpress and Visual Composer (site builder). I want to make a menu on the right (red). It has `250px width`. Visual Composer has an option: "Full width, scratch content". It is enabled in green the `<div>`. But it works in a strange way. It is dynamicly setting width and the `left` value. I set width with calc and it works. Also when I set `margin-left` to `250px` in Developer Tools in Chrome it works. But I added a class `.nowa` in Jquery and set `margin-left` there and it does not work. Because the `left` value takes into account that it is `250px`.
Here is link: [manx.bdl.pl/dworek](http://www.manx.bdl.pl/dworek/)

I just want to move the green `<div>` `250px` to the right...

Answer (score 0):

use important to override the previous classes  like this `margin-left: 0px !important;` and left:0px !important; to vc_`row-fluid` class

```
.vc_row-fluid
{
margin-left: 0px !important;
left: 0px !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding-left: 250px;` to the green div. That should work

Comment: padding-left is not the best solution. Because when I woulde like to set image background it would be cut because of menu...